# Code to calculate a certain arithmetic expression in assemlby

Tags: math, assembly

Expression: z=a+b * b-(36/(b * b)/(1+(25/(b * b)))
I have no idea what data directives I should use and in what order I should write the code.

Comment: Is this a Romanian course?

Comment: http://digital.ubm.ro/?download=2016aclab2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

C = A + B for Z80 CPU:

```
ld a,A
ld b,B
add a,b  ; a = C
```

C = A * B for 68000 CPU:

```
MOVE.W D0,A
MOVE.W D1,B
MULS.W D1,D0    ; D0 = C
```

et cetera ... check your target CPU instruction guide to see what arithmetic operations it does implement directly, and what operand types can be used for them, which registers you have available, and their data type...

Looks like you don't have to write universal math expression parser (this gets tricky quite quickly, once at high-school we had on programming competition the task to write exactly that, and at first we were like "what, a single task for 5h time, I will be done in 30min" ... then after 5h nobody's code passed the full test suite, best were around 80% correct).

So if only this particular expression should be calculated, you can "parse" it by hand, simplifying it down into particular steps involving only single operation and one of intermediate sub-results. Then just write that with your instructions, step by step, like you would calculate that by hand (also make sure you conform to the math expression calculation rules, you know which operations have priority over others? Parentheses override anything, then mul/div first, add/sub later, from left to right, but this is base school math stuff, so unless you are 10y.o., you shouldn't ask this).

If your CPU does not have instruction for division or multiplication, simply implement it by subtraction/addition in loop. It's very lame performance wise, but if you have to ask this question, then one can not expect you would even comprehend more advanced algorithm for these.

Comment: Well roared, lion! :)